Why do type-3/regular languages require a terminal symbol on the right-hand side?
In the Chomsky hierarchy, a type-3/regular language can either be left-regular or right-regular.
Right-regular language have these “production rules”:
A -> a
A -> aB 

Left-regular language have these:
A -> a
A -> Ba

If a language only had rules of the form:
A -> a

it would be guaranteed to finish parsing in exactly the number of “steps” (instances of re-writing) as there were non-terminal symbols in an input string.
If a language had a rule of the form:
A -> B

it would never finish parsing any string containing at least 1 non-terminal symbol, since it has no way to substitute a non-terminal symbol with a terminal one.
If a language had rules of the form:
A -> a
A -> B

assuming A, B, and a are variables, not constants representing only one specific symbol, it should be able to finish parsing, provided the actual rules allow a way to handle all non-terminal symbols in the input alphabet.
Why is it necessary to state that A -> aB? This seems like it would generate additional terminal symbols in the parsed string, which have no effect on the overall properties of the parser.


it would be guaranteed to finish parsing in exactly the number of “steps” (instances of re-writing) as there were non-terminal symbols in an input string.

There are no non-terminal symbols in an input string. Non-terminal symbols are used internally in a grammar, terminal symbols are the only symbols that are included in strings that can be generated by the grammar.
Make sure you’re following the convention of notation correctly. A and B are non-terminals, whereas a is a terminal. If a grammar only has rules of the form A -> a, then any string in its language can have at most one character.
As for your question,

Why is it necessary to state that A -> aB? This seems like it would generate additional terminal symbols in the parsed string, which have no effect on the overall properties of the parser.

I’m not sure what you are asking about. But maybe an example would help. Here is a grammar for generating all strings over the alphabet {a,b,c} where all as must occur before all bs and cs, and all bs must occur before cs.

A -> aA
A -> B
B -> bB
B -> C
C -> cC
C ->

the right hand side of the last rule is the empty string.
You should think of these grammars as generating languages (enumerating a set of strings) first, not as parsers. It will make it clearer what properties the grammars have. If you want to think about them as parsers, you should learn about finite automatons (equivalent to regular grammars) and push down automatons (equivalent to context free grammars). It will eliminate some confusion.

To offer a different explanation:
Suppose you had a grammar with a rule of the form A -> B. You could eliminate this rule from the grammar without affecting the output by, for every rule B -> something, adding a rule A -> something.
This means that any grammar with A -> B rules can be rewritten to get rid of those rules without affecting its output at all. So for mathematical proof purposes, it's easier to just disallow them completely. A computer program for writing context-free grammars should probably allow them for user-friendliness purposes, but that's not what Chomsky is talking about here—he's defining these models in order to prove things about them, and restricting the types of rules helps with that.

So if we want to prove something about grammars, it would be difficult to analyse every possible grammar, so he restricted only to CNF and proved that every CFG can be transformed into CNF, so if we prove some property for CNF then we prove it for all CFG, am I correct in this conclusion?

If all of your rules are of this form:
A -> a
A -> B

Then a single nonterminal can never expand to more than one terminal. Every rule keeps the number of symbols exactly the same. This can only parse trivial languages—you can't parse the language "any number of as", or even "1, 2, or 3 as", with a system like this.
You need a form like A -> aB or A -> BC to avoid this problem, by having one nonterminal expand into two or more symbols.

isn't the term "generate"  more appropriate in case of grammar instead of "parse"?

@mathboy It is, but I was trying to follow the asker's terminology.

I don't understand what he means by parsing, or parser "it would be guaranteed to finish parsing in exactly the number of “steps” (instances of re-writing) as there were non-terminal symbols in an input string." for example here, why do we conclude this? also at the end, what is the question exactly, what he means by "overall properties of parser".

Yes, you are correct, and this is done sometimes, in cases where it simplifies the proof. For regular grammars, CNF isn't very helpful.
